# Знаки препинания при обращении

Tags: пунктуация, частица, междометие, обращение

**"О"** в данном предложении выступает как частица и входит в структуру обращения или же это междометие, которое можно заменить на **"ах"**?

*О(?) ангел мой, не знай, не ведай моей теперешней тоски.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По формулировке вопроса чувствуется, что в [справочник Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126) Вы заглядывали.

Частица ***о***, стоящая перед обращением, никакими знаками препинания от него не отделяется.
***О*** любимые сердцем обманы... (Н. Заболоцкий)

Но перед обращением может стоять и междометие ***о*** (в значении "ах"), которое по правилам отделяется запятой или восклицательным знаком.
***О,*** память сердца! Ты сильней рассудка памяти печальной... (К. Батюшков)

Понятно, что следует различать междометия и омонимичные частицы, имеющие усилительное значение; понятно, что после междометий ставится запятая, после частиц — нет. Но иногда такой выбор сделать довольно сложно, потому что именно это отсутствие или присутствие запятой передает ви́дение и намерения автора.

> И ты ушел. Не за победой,
>   За смертью. Ночи глубоки!
>   О, ангел мой, не знай, не ведай
>   Моей теперешней тоски.

В разных изданиях в стихотворении А. Ахматовой пунктуация различна.
Я все-таки склоняюсь к тому, что запятая должна быть (то есть "о" — междометие, его можно заменить на "ах").

Вот строки А. Волохонского, в которых "о" — частица.

> А в небе голубом горит одна звезда,
>   Она твоя, о ангел мой, она твоя всегда.

Comment: Простите, но, может быть, стоит привести другой пример? О, какая это была любовь - здесь нет обращения.

Comment: Спасибо, Екатерина. Хотелось в ответе показать цитаты, отличные от тех, который приведены в правиле. А конфигурация "междометие + именно обращение" вылетела из головы. P. S. Тогда уж и Вы "поменяйте" Розенталя на ПАС Лопатина. С уважением к Вам...

Comment: Благодарю Вас). ПАС Лопатина мне тоже очень нравится. И Розенталь - это наше всё. Только вот вариативность у него невероятная, примеры некоторые неубедительны, всё на грани - не знаешь, как к этому относиться).

Answer (score 1):

Перед обращением после частицы "о" запятая не ставится. Но "о" бывает и междометием, в этом случае после "о" перед обращением ставится запятая и нужна пауза. Правда, бывает это редко.

*Здесь "о" действительно частица, она не выделяется интонационно, произносится как бы слитно с последующим существительным, поэтому запятой не отделяется.*

**Омонимичные частицы и междометия (о, ах, а) различаются следующим образом: частица имеет усилительное значение и от обращения интонационно не отделяется (не имеет самостоятельного ударения); напротив, междометия интонационно самостоятельны, ударны, после них имеется пауза. Ср.: О поле мое заветное, ты сейчас отдыхаешь после жатвы (Айтм.) — О, ветер! О, снежные бури! (Бл.).** [Розенталь](https://orfhographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=458)